# CSS to Expand, Hide Content on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridview

Container div contains floated left boxes (equally sized) so it looks like grid. One box has a visible content and hidden one. I want to mouse over and see the hidden content expanded so it stays on top of any other box.

I almost got it working except for the last part - hidden content does not stay on top even with z-index applied.

Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ63X/

Comment: Thanks everyone. Please let me review each answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the css to be like this;

```
.item .item-1, .item .item-2{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
}
.item .item-2{
    display:none;
}
.item:hover .item-2{display:block;}
```

hope I helped

/edit -> this way you dont even need javascript..

Comment: +1 I think the background color missing made it appear to not show on top

Comment: without the background color, you don't see clearly which one is on top, but that doesn't change the box beeing "underneath". What chances the behavior to a working one, is making both items position:absolutes, so they stick at the same place

Answer (score 0):

Change the styles for `.item .item-2` as below.

```
.item .item-2{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/ZQ63X/1/)**

Comment: This brings the hidden element on top of the hovered element. Did you check the demo link?

Comment: I think OP meant to have it layered over other elements, as far as z-index goes. I could be wrong, but I think you may have misinterpreted

Answer (score 0):

I added background color and z-index for the hidden elements when revealed... Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/kmacey1249/ZQ63X/3/